# Vue router-link changes style of elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I stumbled upon an odd issue today. I used to use `<a>` tags for switching between links but now I decided to go with `<router-link>` tags instead. For some reason whenever I go from '/' to a different endpoint some styles are not applied and I get unwanted gaps between elements.

| Before the refresh | After I refresh the page |
| --- | --- |
| [image: This is how it looks like with no refresh] | [image: After a refresh] |

There is a similar issue with images (they are squished without a refresh):

| Before the refresh | After I refresh the page |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Before refresh image] | [image: After refresh, image] |

Here is the simplified code(no styling) for the `Header`:

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <div v-for="link of links" :key="link.link">
      <router-link :to="link.link" exact>{{link.name}}</router-link>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'header',
  data() {
    return {
      links: [
        { name: "LINK1", link: "/" },
        { name: "LINK2", link: "/flights/" },
        { name: "LINK3", link: "/experience/" },
        { name: "LINK4", link: "/cakes/" }
      ]
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I believe it is due to components not being loaded properly because after I refresh a page that got rendered incorrectly, everything comes back to normal. Is there a way to wait for the content to fully load before I get redirected? Again, I do not mind using `<a>` tags but I thought I'd ask for some hints first.

EDIT:

This is what happens behind the scenes and it seems like the height changes for some reason. I am using bootstrap's cdn link, is it possible that it might not be rendered properly because of it..?

| Before | After `Cltr + R` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Dev tools before] | [image: Dev tools after] |

Comment: Use your browser's dev-tools to inspect the elements and find out what's going on. The example code in your question is not enough to help you solve this at all

Comment: Sure, I just updated the description.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, I could not derive, where exactly the problem lies. The router links look fine. Vue generally tries to prevent content from loading, if it has been loaded before to improve performance. This could be the case here, but it should be fixable.
I'd use Vue Devtools instead of the normal dev tools. This way you get further insights and you've got that already installed. If you could share a screenshot of the particular element, I could try to analyze the problem further! :)